# In IOS 17 version, pdf Data is getting truncated at the page end and displaying other half in next page in a Pdf render

Tags: css, uikit, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, ios17

I need help for this issue which is happening only in ios 17 ipad devices. I have an application which generates report in a pdf form using uikit built-in functions(UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData, UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo & UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds). This pdf data is dispalying in a particular format with some html and css styling and We are loading the html file as a string to webkit webView which is further helping us by generating the content in pdf format. (our report contains rows & columns which uses div tags and few css properties). If we view the report which is in pdf form, the data is getting truncated for a row horizontally at the page end and displaying the remaining truncated data in the next page.
This issue is happening only in ios 17 updated devices. It was working fine and displaying the data correctly with same html content in previous ios versions.
Please let me know any possible ways through which I can resolve this issue.

I have tried few properties like page-break-X(inside,before,after)- avoid; margin-bottom, padding etc...nothing worked for me.
I also tried by changing header footer heights which I defined manually but failed to resolve this.